# Can I get the comment information from a rails active model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using ruby and activerecord to get information about column.

I am able to get column type and another information using following:

```
Product.table_name
Product.column_names
Product.columns_hash['title'].type
```

My migration script is as follows:

```
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :title, :comment => "Product's title name"
    end
```

how can I get title's `comment ("Product's title name"`)

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the **new [Rails 5 column comments feature](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-table)**, you should be able to call

```
Product.columns_hash['title'].comment
```

to get the comment defined in migration. See [this test](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2db8514d218068cae7b37b7939ed3ba812407105/activerecord/test/cases/comment_test.rb) from Rails source code for more usage examples.